# By how much does the Magic attribute increase attack?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

According to the ingame description the Magic attribute increases the attack of mages. But it doesn't say by how much.

This is rather annoying as I was examining the Lyrium potion that increases Magic for a short time. I know it increases Magic by 30, which seems to be a lot, but I've no idea how much this actually increases damage and wether it is worth it.

So what is the exact effect of increasing the Magic attribute of my mage?

Answer (score 3):

Every point of Magic, for a mage, gives 0.5% attack AND 1% barrier damage.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?